# Launching existing Activity on Notification click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

There is a CountDownTimer created on a fragment. If CountDownTimer is running, user can navigate inside the app or can go outside the app. Whenever user goes outside the CountDownTimer fragment, there should be a notification on the top. If user clicks on the notification, he should be directed to the CountDownTimer fragment and the timer should be showing the correct count down. The below code opens the activity in which CountDownTimer is created. But it launches a new instance of that Activity. Is there any way to get old instance of the same Activity so that I can resume the activity from the same previous state?

```
            {
                Notification.Builder noti = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
                noti.setContentTitle("kick counter").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mom_ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(true);
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), KickCounterActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                noti.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notifier.notify(1, noti.build());
             }
```

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/start-activity-once-notification-clicked.html

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar The code in the linked article will not prevent a new instance of the activity being created, which is what OP wants.

Comment: Do not add flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` to the `Intent`. This flag does nnot alter any behaviour. It is set by Android if the activity is brought to the front under specific circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `Intent`-flags. I'm doing it this way:

```
final Intent openActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
openActivityIntent.setAction("YOUR_ACTION");
openActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(openActivityIntent);
```

In your activity, you will receive the action if you registered it as a listener and act upon it, e.g. navigate to your timer. If you need additional data, you can add it with `openActivityIntent.putExtras(bundle)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the launch mode for the activity to "singleTop", see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Or use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP Intent, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra to the intent. In the activity being launched,you can add something like this.

```
//Notification Intent
notificationIntent.putExtra("Fragment",1);

//MainActivity.class
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras.getInt("Fragment") == 1){
//Load Fragment Here
}
```

Try this out and let me know if it works.

Comment: This will not prevent a new instance of the activity from being created, which is what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this flag

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```